# Rails 4 fields_for form creates duplicate rows in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested

I am new to rails and new to Stackoverflow so please bear with me. I am sure there are things beyond my current query that are not done correctly either.

I have an application which has matricies which have questions and submissions, and submissions have nested answers (to the questions in the matricies).

I have a form for users to submit submissions which displays all the relevant questions for the particular matrix and allows users to answer them. This all renders and saves correctly in the submissions/answers tables in the database.

However, when I edit a submission it correctly prepopulates the fields with the previously entered data, so that part is working correctly, but when I save it simply duplicates it all.

I am sure I have made some mistake in my relationships declarations as a submission should only be allowed one answer to each question, but I have been going round in circles for hours and could well be looking in the wrong place.

You can see the effect here: http://digital-maturity-matrix.herokuapp.com/matrices/1/submissions/2

My model:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :matrix
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers,
    :allow_destroy => true
end
```

My controller:

```
def edit
    @matrix = Matrix.find(params[:matrix_id])
    @submission = Submission.find(params[:id])
    @answers = @submission.answers
    @questions = @matrix.questions
  end

 def update
    @matrix = Matrix.find(params[:matrix_id])
    @user_id = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @submission.update(submission_params)
        format.html { redirect_to matrix_submission_path(@matrix,@submission), notice: 'Submission was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @submission }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @submission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

...

```
def submission_params
      params.require(:submission).permit(:matrix_id, :user_id, :name, :answers_attributes => [:question_answered, :choice, :question_id])
end
```

My form:

```
= form_for([@matrix,@submission]) do |f|
  - if @submission.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(@submission.errors.count, "error")
        prohibited this submission from being saved:
      %ul
        - @submission.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          %li= message
    %br/
  .field  
    = f.hidden_field :matrix_id, :value => params[:matrix_id]
  .field
    = f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id
    = f.fields_for :answers, @answers do |answer|
      .field 
        =answer.label answer.object.question_answered
        = answer.text_field :choice
      .field
        = answer.hidden_field :question_answered
      .field
        = answer.hidden_field :question_id

  .actions
    = f.submit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within seconds of posting this I have found my answer. I think the process of writing the question helped.

For anyone else who stumbles across this, I had missed the inclusion of :id in my nested attributes permitted params. I hadn't realised this was required.

So I needed to replace:

```
def submission_params
      params.require(:submission).permit(:matrix_id, :user_id, :name, :answers_attributes => [:question_answered, :choice, :question_id])
end
```

with:

```
def submission_params
      params.require(:submission).permit(:matrix_id, :user_id, :name, :answers_attributes => [:id, :question_answered, :choice, :question_id])
end
```

Thanks all,
TB